# Closed form of series involving Fibonacci numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ denote the $n$-th Fibonacci number and $\phi$ be the golden ratio, that $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Find a closed form for the sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(5\phi)^n(n+2)} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{F_{k+1} F_{n-k+1}}{k+1}$$

I don't know how to tackle the sum. A closed form exists as the book suggests but there is no hind nor answer on how to tackle it. And I have not come up with some idea to kill this sum. Can anyone help me find a closed form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting $\sigma=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\overline{\sigma}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ we have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}F_k\, x^k = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2} = \frac{-\sigma}{x-\sigma}+\frac{\overline{\sigma}}{x-\overline{\sigma}}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{F_k}{k}\,x^k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sigma x}{1+\overline{\sigma}x}\right)\tag{2}$$
and:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n+1}\sum_{h=0}^{n}\frac{F_{h+1}F_{n-h+1}}{h+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}(1-x-x^2)}\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sigma x}{1+\overline{\sigma}x}\right) \tag{3}$$
so:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^{n+2}}{n+2}\sum_{h=0}^{n}\frac{F_{h+1}F_{n-h+1}}{h+1}=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{5}(1-x-x^2)}\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sigma x}{1+\overline{\sigma}x}\right) \tag{4}$$
and the problem boils down to finding the right $t$ and computing the integral in the RHS, through partial fraction decomposition and $\int\frac{\log x}{x}\,dx=\log^2 x$.

Can you take it from here? The final answer should be something like $\frac{5}{4} \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right) \log\left[\frac{2}{41} \left(13+\sqrt{5}\right)\right]^2$, but I have to check my computations.

Comment: Very nicely done! Your strategy is particularly appealing to me given my affection for logarithmic integrals. Any chance an integral of that type has already been solved here?

Comment: @DavidH: probably it was, but I am not so good at fighting with the search system :)

Comment: Wikipedia on 'Fibonacci' Sec. 4.1.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo: I don't get it. We all know how Fibonacci numbers are defined. We were discussing this particular "dilogarithmic-like" integral, that just gives a squared logarithm.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I can... but I have to make sure I get.. I'll share my thoughts with the community.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I can't bring the integral into the so called "dilog. form" let alone find the appropriate $t$ for subbing ... More hints?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if you can, can you leave here some bibliography about the topic of this question? I read about generating functions but I cant realize how you derive the RHS of (2) from (1). I understand that (1) is the power generating function of Fibonacci numbers and the second is the exponential generating function.

Comment: @Masacroso: there is no EGF involved, in order to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ you just need to integrate termwise $(1)$.

Comment: Oh, yes... what a dumb... I didnt read properly the equation, of course (2) its not EGF, ty @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think you have some typos. You set $\sigma = \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Should you not set $\sigma =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: @Tolaso: that looks fine to me. In order to apply partial fraction decomposition, we have to take $\sigma,\overline{\sigma}$ as the roots of $x^2\color{red}{+}x-1$.

Comment: OK.. !! Any hints on how to evaluate the last integral? I am stuck?

Comment: @Tolaso: you just need to use the partial fraction decomposition appearing in $(1)$ to compute a primitive in terms of a squared logarithm.