# Recursive to explicit form involving Fibonacci

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

I have a recursive formula for a sequence O: $ O_n = O_{n-1} + O_{n-2} + F_{n-1}$ where $F_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci number, $O_1 = 1$ and $O_2 = 2$.

After playing around with it, I found a new formula that might be easier to convert to the form I search: $ O_n = F_{n-3} * O_1 + F_{n-2} * O_2 + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} F_{n-1-k} * F_k$.

Now what I am searching for is an explicit formula for $O_n$ that doesn't include a summation.

I also tried filling in Binet's formula and simplify, to no avail.

[Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383192/closed-form-of-series-involving-fibonacci-numbers) a similar post, but the math is too hard for me, so I can't transform it to fit my problem.

An interesting property I found is that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{O_x}{O_{x-1}}$ is equal to the golden ratio.

Comment: Try a term like $nF_n$

Comment: This is [A029907](https://oeis.org/A029907).  There is some discussion on the linked page, in particular you can find the claim that $O_n=\frac {(n+4)F_n+2nF_{n-1}}5$ which should be easy to verify.

Comment: As another approach, it follows immediately from your definition that $O_n$ satisfies $O_n=2O_{n-1}+O_{n-2}-2O_{n-3}-O_{n-4}$ and the associated characteristic polynomial factors as $(x^2-x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I calculated a few terms and got $(O_n)=(1,2,4,8,15,28,51...)$.

I looked this up in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A029907) and found this formula, which could be made explicit with Binet's formula:

$O_n=\dfrac{(n+4)F_n+2nF_{n-1}}5.$